# is Youtube Comment Webhooks available by google developers?

Tags: google-api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to get a particular YouTube video with its [comments](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/list) whenever someone comments on them.

For example I have agents and I want them to get notified whenever someone comments on their YouTube videos. When they accept notification, they will get that video with its comments.

I do not want to use API's where I have to hit it after a time period just to check for a new comment. I am not able to find YouTube comments webhooks and wanted to confirm if it is available? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

The [YouTube Data api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started) does not have a pub / sub notification endpoint, watch endpoint, or web hook endpoint.

You are going to need to poll the API at intervals, to see if there are any changes.

You may want to consider adding a [Feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803)